# Package 'libboost-python1.58-dev' has no installation candidate

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

When attempting to build an image from a Dockerfile with the following command,

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-openssl-dev python3-pip libboost-python1.58-dev libpython3-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I get the error:

```
Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-openssl-dev python3-pip libboost-python1.58-dev libpython3-dev &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 96c63666f5e1
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libboost-python1.58-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libboost-python1.58-dev' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-openssl-dev python3-pip libboost-python1.58-dev libpython3-dev &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The base image uses Ubuntu 18.04. How can I install this package?

Comment: `libboost-python1.58-dev` is from xenial / 16.* . I'd make a quess that you are trying to install something with instructions specifically for that release. Most likely some a never version of libboost-python will do ..

Comment: @rasjani Yep, that was the issue. using `libboost-python1.65-dev` resolved it.